# Can surface roughing effects on an airfoil Reynolds number be quantified?

Tags: aircraft-design

I am building balsa free flight gliders with a chord of 0.10 meters and a velocity of around 3 meters per second.  This works out to a Reynolds number of around 15,000.

The wings are around 1 meter in span, and are made with the wood grain running lengthwise.  They are thin undercambered (no bottom covering) with maximum thickness of 7 mm at 30% of chord from leading edge.

Because of the roughness of the unfinished grain, is my Reynolds more like 50,000, or am I still down in the range where a flat plate might be better?

Answer (score 7):

Roughness has no influence on the Reynolds number. It will, however, help to trigger a laminar-turbulent transition. That is the reason for dimples in golf balls. Also, roughness will increase the friction drag in turbulent boundary layers.

[image: flat plate friction diagram]

Flat plate friction diagram (picture [source](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/thin-smooth-sign-attached-side-truck-indicated-figure-shown--calculate-friction-drag-lbf-s-q1261825)). Note the horizontal lines: They show that drag does not drop any more with increasing Reynolds number once the surface roughness exceeds a certain value. Roughness is given here relative to the chord length as $\frac{\epsilon}{l}$, with $\epsilon$ being the mean height of the roughness and $l$ the chord length.

The diagram only starts at Re = 100,000, so it is clearly outside the range of your application. If you sand your wooden surface with fine grit sandpaper, I don't expect that the remaining roughness will increase drag. At those Reynolds numbers it might be advantageous to add a trip wire in order to induce a transition to turbulent flow – see the [golf ball example](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24752/is-a-golf-ball-surface-a-good-idea-for-wings-or-fuselage/24759#24759).

Comment: Frisbee grooves may be a bit closer.  Roughness to chord length ratio interesting way of trying it, as well as location on the airfoil.

Comment: What's causing the increasing in drag with Re for the low surface roughness lines?

Comment: @Jimmy Don't confuse "increasing drag" and "increasing the drag coefficient". For a given structure, lower Re means lower velocity and the drag coefficient is multiplied by $v^2$ to get the drag force. But for *laminar* flow the drag *force* is proportional to $v$ not $v^2$, so the drag coefficient used in the conventional formula appears to be bigger at low Re even though the drag force is less.

Comment: @alephzero I didn't confuse. 1e6 Re is a standard wind tunnel Re for engineering design. No one will say the drag is linear to V.

Comment: What I'm getting is that larger roughness to chord ratio is "completely turbulent" at lower Reynolds, therefor "transitional turbulent" at a lower airspeed, where drag reduction occurs.  This may have been what Kline-Fogelman were after, but their "disrupter" steps may have been too large.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni and were on the wrong side. The graph is for a flat plate while you need to look at a cambered airfoil with an angle of attack. The pressure distribution is different and so are the needs for the boundary layer.

Comment: @Peter Kampf well, I'm starting to see why they didn't bother to go below 10^5 for full scale aircraft, some very interesting things going on at lower Reynolds (even down to insect wings).  All part of an amazing spectrum.