# How is shear stress distributed on an airfoil?

Tags: aerodynamics, airfoil

I know the pressure distribution on an airfoil but not shear stress. How is shear stress distributed on an airfoil?

[image]

Comment: How are you defining shear stress in your question? Front to back? Inboard to outboard?

Comment: Inboard to outboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shear stress is proportional to the [speed gradient](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16953/how-do-insects-decrease-aircraft-performance/16956#16956) at the wall. This means:

1. A thin boundary layer produces more shear than a thick one. The boundary layer is thinnest right next to the stagnation point and grows in thickness downstream.
2. A turbulent boundary layer will create much more shear stress than a laminar one. Most of the shear on an airfoil happens past the [transition](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/36935/is-airflow-ever-laminar-in-the-boundary-layer-near-the-wing-leading-edge/36939#36939) point.
3. Higher speeds cause higher shear stresses. Therefore, the suction area on the upper side of the airfoil produces more shear stress than the pressure area on the lower side. In a separation bubble with speed reversal at the wall you will even get a small amount of "shear thrust".

The shear acts along the local flow direction, so it is mostly front-to-back. Only near the wingtips, where lateral flow becomes non-negligible, will a lateral shear component become noticeable.

[image: E502mod at 3° AoA, friction plot]

Friction drag over chord for an E502mod airfoil at 3° AoA. Blue: Top surface, Red: Bottom surface. Source: XFOIL 6.97. The transition points are clearly visible: It is where shear shoots up again at mid-chord. Note the separation bubble ahead of the transition point on the bottom side: It is marked by negative values of shear.

Comment: For clarification, @DavidTeahay this is the exact answer to the question as worded. But, at first read, I thought the question was more about the shear distribution over a wing. Shear and moments would be used for rib/spar configuration and sizing analyses. FYI. Sorry to bother if you already know the difference. ;)