# Distance where transition from laminar to turbulent boundary takes place

Tags: aerodynamics, reynolds-number, laminar-flow

How do we work out where the distance from the leading edge the laminar boundary layer would turn into a turbulent boundary layer? Assuming we have been given the length of the plate, speed, dynamic viscosity of air and the Reynolds number?

Comment: For help with homework problems, always show what you have tried so far.  Otherwise you come across as asking people to do your homework for you, which I assume is not what you wish.

Comment: Related: [Is airflow ever laminar in the boundary layer, near the wing leading edge?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/36935/3201)